# Galaxy s2 will not boot, wrong bootloader

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, bootloader, odin

My Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I1900 won't boot.

1. I tried to update to ICS with Kies which crashed, wherefore I unplugged the USB to start over.
2. Now my phone had no OS, and wouldn't respond to Kies anymore.
3. By mistake I flashed the downloaded original firmware into the bootloader section in Odin.
4. Now it just shows a screen that says Samsung Galaxy SII GT-I9100
5. Next I tried to recover with Odin. I flashed another firmware, and the old bootloader and attached a PIT file which worked for me earlier.

I want to now how I can make it work again. I have been looking for days for the following files:

1. Original .PIT file
2. Original Firmware
3. Original Bootloader

What should I do? I am using Odin v1.85.

Comment: Its a lesson why you should always keep Nandroid backups..

Comment: i dont think nandroid will help anyhow. ODIN will be the only hope, really. [This](http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/6349-Firmware-I9100DXKI2-2.3.3-(GINGERBREAD)-for-Samsung-Galaxy-I9100-ODIN-PIT) might be the files you need.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, my problem is that i need a bootloader file... I, by mistake, replaced the original bootloader with the firmware... Now it will not boot.. I was not able to download the second file...When i try to wipe data/factory reset it says that it cannot access to '/system/csc/HTD/system'.

Comment: How did you manage to flash it over the bootloader?  Did you load it in the wrong field in Odin?

Comment: @Ryan see he is able to access recovery... means, nandroid backup could have helped..

Comment: @MatthewRead Yep, i mistakenly loaded the firmware into the bootloader section... Can it be fixed if i access a nandroidbackup from another galaxy s2?

Comment: Nope.  You'll need to flash a dump of the bootloader and hope it works, and then probably re-flash a ROM.  You can get the bootloader [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/5kjpJwew) among other places but I've verified that one. @SachinShekhar Nandroid doesn't back up or flash the bootloader.

Comment: @Matthew A full Nandroid backup saves entire ROM.. which indeed contains bootloader..

Comment: Thanks alot @MatthewRead, Now i have downloaded the file, i will try in a moment...

Comment: @SachinShekhar As the noob i am: Where will i find a fully functional and original ROM, and how should i download to my phone?

Comment: It seems that something is missing...
When i am trying to wipe data/ factory reset, it says that it cannot acces '/system/csc/HTD/system/'
What does that mean and how do i solve it :D

Answer (score 1):

Go to [samfirmware](http://samfirmware.com)

Get your original firmware from there and keep the selected file in **PDA** option in Odin.

Do not tick any other option; just put your handset into 'Download Mode' and connect it to pc.

When Odin displays 'CONNECT', click on 'Start' and wait until it starts flashing then; you will be able to use your phone.

Comment: -1 from me for the poor lazy answer in which I had to take the trouble in re-editing it to make it more *natural* for others to follow. In future - please refrain from using text speak, *don't care if you're on the phone answering this*